# Webpack Hot Module Replacement does not inject the updated code

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-hmr

I've been trying to configure the Webpack 2 Hot Module Replacement by using Webpack-Dev-Server.

`webpack.config.js` is the following:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const Webpack = require('webpack');
  const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

  const HotModuleReplacement = new Webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();
  const NamedModulesPlugin = new Webpack.NamedModulesPlugin();
  const NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin = new Webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin();

  const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css');
  const extractSCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

  const config = {
      entry: [
          'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
          // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server
          // and connect to the provided endpoint
         'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
         // bundle the client for hot reloading
         // only- means to only hot reload for successful updates
         './src/index.js',
      ],
      output: {
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
          filename: 'bundle.js',
          publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
          hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
          hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json',
      },
      module: {
          rules: [
              {
                  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                  exclude: [
                      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                  ],
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
                  },
              },
              {
                  test: /\.scss$/,
                  loader: extractSCSS.extract({
                      fallback: 'style-loader',
                      use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                  }),
              },
              {
                  test: /\.css$/,
                  loader: extractCSS.extract({
                      fallback: 'style-loader',
                      use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
                  }),
              },
          ],
      },
      plugins: [
          extractCSS,
          extractSCSS,
          HotModuleReplacement,
          NamedModulesPlugin,
          NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin,
      ],

      devtool: 'source-map',
      devServer: {
          publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
          contentBase: './',
          inline: true,
          hot: true,
          historyApiFallback: true,
          stats: {
              colors: true,
          },
      },
   };

   module.exports = config;
```

I've got this folder structure:

```
/
/src
/src/index.js
/src/index.scss
```

and I thought that I needed to use the HMR API in the `index.js` like so:

```
import MockComponent from './MockComponent/MockComponent';

export default class App {
    constructor() {
        this.mock = new MockComponent();
    }
    render() {
        return `<div class="element">${this.mock.render()}</div>`;
    }
}

let app = {};
app = new App();
const mainDiv = document.querySelector('#root');
mainDiv.innerHTML = app.render();

// Hot Module Replacement API
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

The is issue is that when I do a change in the code in the console I got:

[image: chrome console]

but then the HMR seems it's not doing any change on the rendered.

Could anybody please help me out on this?

Many Thanks

Comment: did you end up resolving this? Did that answer help at all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I haven't sorted it. I eliminated the `ExtractTextPlugin` from my dev environment but now I get a `[HMR] Update failed: Error: Manifest request to http://localhost/hot/hot-update.json timed out.
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:38:22)` output in the console when it comes to replace the component style (please see this branch https://github.com/andrixb/WebpackSassStarter/blob/testHMR/webpack.config.js). I've got two separate configurations for dev and prod so I'm not using the environment var as you showed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you did not `disable` the `ExtractTextPlugin` while in development mode. Without disabling it the `fallback` loader you're passing won't run, in this case the `style-loader`, and the `ExtractTextPlugin` doesn't support HMR itself.

In production you won't want the `ExtractTextPlugin` to be disabled, so one approach to this is using one config would be to use the `--env` flag. Note that, usually it is recommended to use to separate configurations, one for production and one for development although you can use tools like [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) to share the common bits.

So in your *package.json* you'll want to update your scripts and then change your config to be a function so it can accept the `env` object as a parameter.

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --env.dev",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  ...
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
...

const config = (env = {}) => ({
  ...
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css',
      disable: env.dev === true
    })
  ]
})
```

I'm excluding the a lot here for brevity but that should give you a pretty good idea. See below for the versions I'm using...

```
extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.0
style-loader@0.14.0
webpack@2.2.1
webpack-dev-server@2.4.2
```

It's import to note that, while you can enable HMR with `hot: true` in `devServer` and a `new HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` in `plugins`, other loaders and configuration changes are needed to produce "live" changing in the browser for different types of code... here's a few that come to mind:

- [Style Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader): as you are using already
- [React Hot Loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader): for live reloading of react components
- [Vue Loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader): for live reloading of vue components

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved (please refer to this repo https://github.com/andrixb/WebpackSassStarter):

- Added in `webpack.config.js` `HtmlWebpackPlugin` with the following configuration:

  `new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'FE Build Setup',
          hash: true,
          template: './src/index.html',
      }),`
- Moved inside the `src` folder the `index.html` that was outside and removed static script and link tag (`index.html` now is used just a template)
- Removed from `webpack.config.js` 
  in `entry`

  `'webpack-dev-server/client?    http://localhost:8080',
  // bundle the client for webpack-dev-server
  // and connect to the provided endpoint
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  // bundle the client for hot reloading
  // only- means to only hot reload for successful updates`

  and in `output`:

  `publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
  hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json',`
- Removed (in `webpack.config.js`) `ExtractTextPlugin` from dev environment as suggested by **@Skip Jack**
- Edited the `devServer` configuration in `webpack.config.js`